# Using a Map type attribute in aura:if

Tags: lightning-aura-components, map, aura, aura-attribute

Trying to create a custom Navigation Bar and display menu entries based on user privileges.

I defined this attribute in my component:

```
<aura:attribute name="navItemPrivs" type="Map" default="{ Task: false }"/>
```

In the JS controller and helper I'm able to access and modify it using navItemPrivs['Task'], but when I try and use it inside an aura:if expression:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!and(v.navItemLabel1 != undefined, v.navItemPrivs['Task'] == true}">
```

I get an error:

> expecting a positive integer, found ''Task'' at column 50 of expression: and(v.navItemLabel1 != undefined, v.navItemPrivs['Task'] == true

I can't access it using v.navItemPrivs[0] because the "0" key isn't defined (nor do I want it to be).

Is there something I'm doing wrong and this isn't the way to do it? Because I don't see why I would not be able to access Map values if they exist in the framework..

Comment: I suggest create a new child component and pass the map in that component. in that component js controller use javascript method to get the value from map and check if it task = true then hide/show

Comment: Hm, good idea, I'll try that + extend my current component to still be able to use the code there.
Hopefully the LockerService won't break anything.
Thanks.

Comment: Didn't work.. got the same error when doing this:
<c:navBarItem testAttr="{!v.navItemPrivs['Task']}" />

Comment: No..... you need to send this map to controller and check it contains task or not.... check this answer http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/111175/18731 how used inner component

Comment: Seems rather redundant creating a component then if I can just do the same and hide/show each element by ID in the original component, no?
I was hoping to use something that's built into the framework (like aura:if).

Comment: Yeah I wish I could say that.. But in lightning we can't use map till now.. May be later they will add this feature

Comment: You can access the attribute as `v.navItemPrivs.Task` and that should work just fine. However what you can't do is bind to dynamically named keys (e.g. you can't do `v.myMap[v.myKey]` in Lightning so far). Be aware that under the current way Locker functions (as of Summer '16 Patch 10.0) if you want a Map/Object key binding to be successful the key must exist when you first push the object to the `v.attribute` it will reside in.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesT, that did the trick.
I'm creating a static map with values already residing inside upon load, so that won't be a problem.

Comment: Oh lovely. How about I put the same content into an answer then.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can access the attribute as `v.navItemPrivs.Task` and that should work just fine. Object properties are accessible by dot notation but not brackets unless they are integers.

Unfortunately you can't bind to dynamically named keys (e.g. you can't do `v.myMap[v.myKey]` in Lightning so far). Be aware that under the current way Locker functions (as of Summer '16 Patch 10.0) if you want a Map/Object key binding to be successful the key must exist when you first push the object to the v.attribute it will reside in.

Comment: I've opened an idea for accessing keys with dynamic names. https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lK1aQAE