# Is it not possible to use Dynamic binding of sObject fields in a Lightning Component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, dynamic-binding, outputtext

I'm trying to loop a list of sObject fields and displaying the fields as column in a table.

In Visualforce, we could bind an sObject field like `value="{!Contact[fieldName]}"`. But I'm unable to make this happen in a Lightning Component.

I'm trying to output my field data like this:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.contactColumns}" var="col">
<td>
<ui:outputText value="{!'contact.' + col.fieldName}"></ui:outputText>
</td>
</aura:iteration>
```

But it is displaying Empty output, without any value.

Am I doing it wrong in preparing dynamic field value binding for `ui:outputText` in above code?

Ive even tried using `force:outputField` without any luck and same empty value output:

```
<force:outputField value="{!'contact.' + col.fieldName}" />
```

Comment: everything is case sensitive. are you sure your field names are correct? For example `col.fieldName` is not the same as `col.fieldname`.   Without seeing your actual code (and js controller) I can't really help.

Comment: Also, i'm not sure what you're trying to do with the `value="{!'contact.' + col.fieldName}"`.  is that `.contact` for dynamic binding, or display purposes?  Please post all relevant code.

Comment: Yes my bad, i ll add full code in my post.

Comment: Unlike visualforce, you cannot have dynamic field binding in LC.Check [this](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/111175/20830) answer out it might help

Comment: @Praveen - Thanks a lot man, that is exactly the trick I was missing, I'm able to get the issue resolved now. Making Iteration loop over a sub component and that subcomponent init handler populating output value made the values populate in my component. If you could point that out in Answer, I could mark that as an accepted answer then :-)

Comment: @Praveen you are posting some great answers in comments all over, please post them as answers.

Comment: @Rao I really appreciate your advice.But I'm not sure if the above comment should be posted as answer.Since it point's to another user's answer.I don't want to take credit away.