# Lightning Nested Iteration

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have apex controller that returns `Map<String, List<sObject>>`. I want to iterate through keys and through sObjects inside of parent iteration.

Apex:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Map<String, List<sObject>> returnSObjectMap() {...}
```

Lightning Controller:

```
getsobjectMap : function(component) {
var action = component.get("c.returnSObjectMap");
action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
    if (a.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
        var sobjectFields = a.getReturnValue();
        var sobjectFieldsFinal = [];
        for (var key in sobjectFields) {
            sobjectFieldsFinal.push({value:sobjectFields[key], key:key});
        }               
        component.set('v.sobjectsMap',sobjectFieldsFinal);
    } else if (a.getState() === "ERROR") {

    }
});

$A.enqueueAction(action);}
```

Component:

```
...
<aura:attribute name="sobjectsMap" type="List"/>
...
<aura:iteration items="{! v.sobjectsMap }" var="sobjectList" indexVar="key">
    <apex:iteration items="{! sobjectList }" var="sobject">
    ...
    </apex:iteration>
</aura:iteration>
```

I'm receiving an error when trying so save on line:

```
<apex:iteration items="{! sobjectList }" var="sobject">
```

Error: No COMPONENT named markup://apex:iteration found

How can I iterate over inner list?

Comment: check this answer https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/111175/18731

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misspelled it. It's `aura:iteration` instead of `apex:iteration`

```
<aura:iteration items="{! v.sobjectsMap }" var="sobjectList" indexVar="key">
    <aura:iteration items="{! sobjectList }" var="sobject">
    ...
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:iteration>
```

Comment: you added the same "iteration"

Comment: no, you are using `apex` I'm using `aura`

Comment: sobjectsMap – is not a map. It's list as you can see in component.

Comment: if so, `aura:iteration` will fix it.

Comment: lol, thank you! How can I missed that... Saved now :) But for some reason I can't display values like: {! sobject.Name }

Comment: your structure looks like you would need to use sobject.value and sobject.key